# How to calculate with SQL the number of things between dates and times?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Query Records and Group by a block of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035950/query-records-and-group-by-a-block-of-time)

I am stuck in the middle of a project. The problem is to calculate total number of stuffs given dates and times. Here are the tables that I have:
Table 1: Holding date and time information

```
Timeid | startDate  | endDate    | startTime | endTime  |

1  | 2012-07-05 | 2012-07-05 | 08:30:00  | 10:00:00 |

2  | 2012-07-05 | 2012-07-06 | 10:30:00  | 12:00:00 |

3  | 2012-07-04 | 2012-07-07 | 08:30:00  | 17:00:00 |

4  | 2012-07-05 | 2012-07-08 | 12:30:00  | 14:00:00 |

5  | 2012-07-04 | 2012-07-06 | 12:30:00  | 14:00:00 |

6  | 2012-07-05 | 2012-07-05 | 08:30:00  | 10:00:00 |

7  | 2012-07-05 | 2012-07-06 | 10:30:00  | 12:00:00 |
```

Table 2: Stroing the stuff information related to id information which is related to date and time.

```
Autoid | TimeId | stuffId | amountOfStuff |

1      |     1    |   2     |    1   |      

2      |     2    |   2     |    1   |  

3      |     3    |   2     |    1   |  

4      |     4    |   2     |    1   |  

5      |     5    |   2     |    1   |  

6      |     6    |   2     |    1   |  

7      |     7    |   2     |    1   |
```

as it is seen in the tables, there is a relation between tables for the timeID. I want to calculate how many stuff (amountofstuff) in used for a given date range.

For example, I need the total amountofStuff of stored stuffs in table2  for  the date startDate:05.07.2012 and endDate:05.07.2012 and startTime: 07:00:00 endTime: 21:00:00. However if the times are not crossed/cut, then it should not be count. For this query result should be "3"... a figure for the explanation is: 
please note that the numbers below are TimeIds.

|--1--| |--2--| |--4--|

|-----------3-----------------------|

|--6--| |--7--| |--5--|

and the result is "3". the amount of stuff in used from startDate:05.07.2012 and endDate:05.07.2012 and startTime: 07:00:00 endTime: 21:00:00.

I hope I have explained everything clearly NOW. Let me know for further information. 
Thank you.

Comment: You *really* should store your dates and times in columns of appropriate [temporal types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html): that will make this problem considerably easier.

Comment: What do you mean by "temporal types". Actually I just wrote it like this. Dates are in date type of mysql, times are in time data type. so Actual dates are seen like "2012-07-05".

Comment: @deepnote You should clarify that within the query post.

Comment: Why do then compare for time? We need to compare only same date for start and end, isn't it?

Comment: Given the data above and your example query to find "*total number of stored stuffs in table2 for the date startDate:05.07.2012 and endDate:05.07.2012 and startTime: 07:00:00 endTime: 21:00:00*", what would you expect the result to be?  I don't see any events for which the times are "*crossed/cut*", so would the result be 0?

Comment: sometimes for samedate, sometimes between dates. so it could be from 05.07.2012 to 09.07.2012 or from 05.07.2012 or 05.05.2012. What I mean is dates and times are changeable.

Comment: So are you trying to sum the `number` column in table 2 between a certain date/time range? It appears that the `number` column is amount of an item (or 'stuff' as you call it) that something happened to between the related dates and times in table 1.

Comment: It's still unclear.  When should an event be included in the sum?  If it falls entirely within the specified range?  If its dates fall at least partially in the range but the times fall entirely within the range?  If its dates fall at least partially in the range and its times fall at least partially in the range?  If its dates fall strictly partially in the range and its times fall entirely in the range?  etc.  So many possible interpretations!  Please give the expected output for your sample query.

Comment: @hradac you are right. "number" column is the amount of stuffs. I want to sum the amount of the stuffs given date and time range for a query.  The given date and time range is between the dates and times in Table 1.

Comment: @deepnote: You mean stuffs between range for given range of date and times.

Comment: @Somnath Muluk the sum number(amount) of stuffs for range of date and times.

Comment: What is datatype of startDate,endDate, endTime and startTime?

Comment: I have edited the question and tried to more specific. Sorry for any inconvenience